# Getting R Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels

Tags: r, model, prediction, confusion-matrix

[image: dataset]

This is my R code:

```
#scaling the data
scale_data <- as.data.frame(lapply(dataset[,2:12], scale))

#Spliting the dataset into training and testing sets

set.seed(123)
data_split <- createDataPartition(scale_data$FBGoals,p = 0.8, list = FALSE)
trainData <- scale_data[data_split,]
testData <- scale_data [-data_split,]

#Defining the training control for model training

ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 5, repeats = 10)

#Running glm model

glmModel <- train(FBGoals ~ ., data = trainData, method = "glm", trControl = ctrl)

#predicting the model
    testML <- predict(glmModel,testData)

#running confusionMatrix for accuracy of the model
    confusionMatrix(data = testML, reference=testData$FBGoals)

Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels.
```

Tried:

```
confusionMatrix(testML,as.factor(testData$FBGoals))
   confusionMatrix(testML,testData$FBGoals)
```